# Java instanceof generic type

Tags: java

I am wondering why the first line compiles but the second not

```
new Integer(1) instanceof Comparable<?>;
new Integer(1) instanceof Comparable<Integer>;
```

The error msg is:

```
illegal generic type for instanceof
```

Thanks

Comment: Generic type arguments are erased in Java - that information is not available at runtime, so you can't make a runtime check on it.

Answer (score 1):

From [JLS Sec 15.20.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2):

> It is a compile-time error if the ReferenceType mentioned after the instanceof operator does not denote a reference type that is reifiable (§4.7).

From [Sec 4.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.7)

> A type is reifiable if and only if one of the following holds:
>
> ...
>
> - It is a parameterized type in which all type arguments are unbounded wildcards (§4.5.1).
>
> ...